# DEBUG HTTP verb may show server debugging information. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28VS.80%29.aspx for details

Tags: apache2

i am checking my server using Nikto,like this--

root@qolsys-desktop:~/nikto -h http://localhost:8080/

### - Nikto v2.1.4

- DEBUG HTTP verb may show server debugging information.
- 6448 items checked: 0 error(s) and 3 item(s) reported on remote host

  ### + End Time:           2016-02-20 16:05:16 (7 seconds)
- 1 host(s) tested

my question is that --
Ques-- how i fixed this warning in Apache-
 DEBUG HTTP verb may show server debugging information.
--if anyone know please help me.